# Loading user routes from address bar with polymerfire

Tags: polymer, polymer-starter-kit, polymerfire

I've got a [polymer starter kit](https://github.com/PolymerElements/polymer-starter-kit) app with several sub routes and various types of records associated with those routes. An example URL might be `//myapp/records/{recordId}/subRoute`. I would like the app state to persist on reload. I've tried like so:

```html
<app-route
    route="{{route}}"
    pattern="/records/:recordId"
    data="{{routeData}}"
    tail="{{subroute}}"
></app-route>
<app-route
    route="{{subroute}}"
    pattern="/:page"
    data="{{subRouteData}}"
></app-route>

<firebase-document
    id="recordsDocument"
    path="/records/[[routeData.recordId]]"
    data="{{record}}"
></firebase-document>

...

<script>
  routePageChanged(page) { // takes subRouteData.page
    if (!user) {
      set('page', 'login'),
    } else if (!routeData.recordId) {
      set('page', 'start')
    } else {
      set('page', page)
    }
  }
</script>
```

But under these conditions, the browser will always end up on the login page, since routePageChanged is called before firebase responds with the user.
How can I get my app to correctly load from address bar routes that depend on the existence of an auth'd firebase `user` when that object does not exist until firebase responds?

Answer (score 0):

You can do several things. Since you are waiting for the user, you need the user object to be initialized.

In firebase-auth, there is a user object:

```
 user: {
   type: Object,
   readOnly: true,
   value: null,
   notify: true
 },
```

You could listen for changes on that object.

An alternative way is to handle it like this:

```
this.$.auth.signInWithPopup()
.then(function(response) {// successful authentication response here})
.catch(function(error) {// unsuccessful authentication response here});
```

On success of above code, the user object should be set, you could check your initial routing with that.

I can't think of any other options on top of my head.

Other then that, I have to recommend the docs, ofcourse :P

https://github.com/firebase/polymerfire/blob/master/firebase-auth.html

Comment: If i understand your suggestion, you're recommending that I maybe set a key called "firebaseUserLoaded" and test for it before executing anything in `_routePageChanged` on any of my routes. I would then seemingly need to set up an error case if there are network issues?

Comment: yeah, in your routing function you could have an if statement that checks if boolean firebaseUserLoaded is true. You set this object in the firebase-auth callback. If a network error comes up, it will go into the error flow of the javascript i have shown above, in that case its up to you to set the variable to true or false